# Json Parsing in Android with multiple same rows

Tags: android, json

Well,it is simple yet I am finding confused to extract the info.Could you give a look here:

formatted JSON Data

```
[  
   {  
      "catalogName":"a",
      "categoryName":"aa",
      "subCategoryName":"aaa",
      "price":888.0,
   },
   {  

      "catalogName":"b",
      "categoryName":"bb",
      "subCategoryName":"bbb",
      "productName":"hjb",
      "price":9.0,
   }
]
```

I would be printing this in my android app.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using for loop?

Comment: Your Json Format is `invalid` first change it .

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do in my code:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
httpGet.setHeader("Accept",       "application/json");
httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpClient httpClient    = new DefaultHttpClient();         
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine   statusLine   = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
// Check StatusLine result ....

// Convert response to a JSon Array:
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
httpResponse.getEntity().writeTo(baos);
baos.close();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(baos.toString())

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i)
{
    // Extract values from JSON row:
    JSONObject jsonObject      = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String     catalogName     = jsonObject.has("catalogName")     ? jsonObject.getString("catalogName") : "";
    String     categoryName    = jsonObject.has("categoryName")    ? jsonObject.getString("categoryName") : "";
    String     subCategoryName = jsonObject.has("subCategoryName") ? jsonObject.getString("subCategoryName") : "";
    String     productName     = jsonObject.has("productName")     ? jsonObject.getString("productName") : "";
    double     price           = jsonObject.has("price")           ? jsonObject.getString("price") : 0.;

    // Do stuff with data:
    ...
}
```

Please note that if a row misses a value (like `productName`) you must handle it. In the example I assign a default value but maybe it's not the best choice.

Comment: for 2nd set should I use again JSONObject jObject2     = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);then write all those things?

Comment: I modified the example code: the code loops on all records and the missing fields are handled with default values.

Comment: will it be dynamic ?

Comment: What you mean with dynamic? If the number of rows changes of course the code will handle all of the, if the values are missing in some rows the code assign default values to them

Comment: here just example of 2 sets,but in future number of sets will be higher

Comment: In the example the for loops from 0 to jsonArray.length, that matches the number of sets contained in the json object, whatever it is

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray("YOUR_JSON_ARRAY_NAME");  //Must be case sensitive

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
JSONObject current_job= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

String catalogName= current_job.getString("catalogName");
//same for other fields. KEY must be case sensitive
    ... 
    ...
    }
```

Comment: it will print everything.. check for loop.

Comment: check edit. you can check if it has particular param by using .has()

Comment: for 1st set, I used to hold String w1=jsonObject.getString("catalogName"); and should I use for 2nd set String s2=jsonObject.getString("catalogName"); but here json object will be different than the 1st one set?

Comment: check has() method. and if worked consider accepting the answer!  thanx!

Comment: @ndeokar: you r right, here has() method will work. Check this doc - https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Cyborg91: You will need to parse each JSON Key in separate String. Please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: @Cyborg91: Check this link for has() method - https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Onkar i dont see my answer as wrong anywhere and it should not be downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

This is a JSONArray :-) Parse it with this:

```
String json = /** your JSON **/
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
```

And now you can take the data out of the object with getJSONObject(int index) :-)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a JSON parsing library, such as Gson. It is fast and very simple to use.
https://github.com/google/gson

If you have a following class:

```
class Catalog{
    private String catalogName;
    private String categoryName;
    private String subCategoryName;
    private String productName;
    private double price;

    /** Getter, setters, optional: toString, constructor... **/
}
```

To parse it simply call:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Catalog>>() {}.getType();
List<Catalog> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(YOUR_JSON_STRING, listType);
```

Instead of this "confusing" code for `listType` you can use also `Class` (see documentation), but this is not possible in your case, as provided JSON format is a direct list of elements, it is not wrapped. For using a class you would have to wrap this JSON with another element.

Comment: I would recommend something better than Gson, such as Moshi  https://github.com/square/moshi  or LoganSquare https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare

Comment: what are the advantages / disadvantages compared to GSON?

Comment: check this benchmark http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=LoganSquare-master/BenchmarkDemo/app/src/main/java/com/bluelinelabs/logansquare/demo/MainActivity.java